# Make rectangular thumbnails square for large screen size in a bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I'm working on implementing a data grid of square images in bootstrap. One requirement is that the grid remain square and the images shrink on transition to smaller screen widths. Below I have my current implementation, it works great for large images, but when I try to use an image below a certain size the thumbnails appear square for large screen widths. Can some one advise me on how to adapt this for smaller images? Also I have a strong preference to do this with out adding css and if that's not possible I'd like to find a minimally invasive solution.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/7620/)

html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <a class="thumbnail" href="http://www.google.com"><img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="http://www.op-art.co.uk/op-art-gallery/var/albums/your-op-art/GDHarley_OP-ART_%2311.jpg?m=1382213140" /></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <a class="thumbnail" href="http://www.google.com"><img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="http://www.op-art.co.uk/op-art-gallery/var/albums/your-op-art/GDHarley_OP-ART_%2311.jpg?m=1382213140" /></a>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <a class="thumbnail" href="http://www.google.com"><img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="http://davidsimpson.me/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/icon1281.png" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <a class="thumbnail" href="http://www.google.com"><img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="http://davidsimpson.me/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/icon1281.png" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Smaller images need to have 100% width therefore you have to use CSS code, simply add this CSS class:

```
.full-width
{
    width:100%;
}
```

and then use it in the  tag:

```
<img class="img-responsive img-rounded full-width" ... />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although this requires extra css, I like that it's only one line. I am however having the issue that when I implement this it stretches my images to a larger size and I lose resolution.